# Fourier transform of Green Function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

To work on a electrostatic potential, we need to use fourier transformation of the equation,

$$\nabla^2 G (R) = \delta (R)$$

We get the equation:

$$G(R) = \frac{1}{({2 \pi})^3} \int d^3 k \ \ \ e^{i \vec{k} \cdot  \vec{R}} G( \tilde{R})$$

I know that the cube over $2 \pi$ due to the three dimensional space but why do we get the  $ G( \tilde{R})$ in the right side of the Fourier transformation?

Comment: I think you are just writing that $G$ is the inverse Fourier transform of its own Fourier transform, except that that would be written more like $G(R)=\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^3} \int d^3 k e^{ik \cdot R} \hat{G}(k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works roughly like this:

You Fourier-transform both sides of the initial equation $\Delta G(R) = \delta(R)$. The differential operators in
$\Delta = \sum \partial_i^2$ should transform into some multiplicative operators $\sum k_i^2$. You can then invert algebraically to get $G(R)$ and finally back-transform that expression.